# MYSQL: Get zero values in group by clause

Tags: mysql

I need zero values also in group by clause .Have read almost all question related to this on Stackoverflow, but none of the solutions have worked.

My Table is

[image]

Need to get sum of score grouped by day of month.But I am not getting zero against the days not present in the table

```
SELECT SUM(engagement_score), DAY(creation_dt)
FROM qee_emp_engagement_index
RIGHT JOIN (
SELECT 1 AS index1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 9) AS a ON a.index1 =  DAY(creation_dt)
WHERE org_id = 1
GROUP BY a.index1
ORDER BY a.index1 ASC
```

Comment: if the date is not present in table then how its possible to get it with zero, You can do that by processing in php, i think there is not any need of mysql.

Comment: @HarshSanghani True, but the OP hasn't mentioned PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the query using a `left join` rather than a `right join` (the logic of `left join` makes more sense to me:  keep all the rows in the first table).  But, your problem is the `where` clause.  That logic should go in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(eei.engagement_score), 0), a.index1
FROM (SELECT 1 AS index1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 UNION ALL
      SELECT 8 UNION ALL
      SELECT 9
     ) a LEFT JOIN
     qee_emp_engagement_index eei
     ON a.index1 =  DAY(eei.creation_dt) AND eei.org_id = 1
GROUP BY a.index1
ORDER BY a.index1 ASC;
```

In addition, the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` should use the column from the driving table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE(creation_date), SUM(engagement_score) FROM table_name GROUP BY DATE(creation_date)
```

There is no need to do that weird right join in your code

If you want to group it by the day of month and not by the date, use `DAY()` instead of `DATE()`

**EDIT:** 
If you want a zero when the day of month doesn't exist, try this:

```
    SELECT d, SUM(score) FROM
 ((SELECT creation_date AS d, engagement_score AS score FROM table_name) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT d, 0 AS engagement_score FROM table_name WHERE d BETWEEN 1 AND 31)) 
GROUP BY d
```

Comment: Thanks Tobis for reply. But my table might not contain engagement score for every date. In that case, I want to show zero for that day/date

Comment: Ah, edited my answer. (Sorry for the ugly code, I'm on my phone right now). Not 100% sure if this solution works, but you might try

Answer (score 0):

You can do right join between your table and a temp table containing all dates in a range.

Dates can be generated using below query

```
select a.Date 
from (
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a
where a.Date between '2015-01-01' and '2017-01-01'
```